# Laravel eloquent has hasmany of hasmany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to show all company who has photo attachment?

company:

```
id | name
```

user:

```
id | name | company_id
```

post:

```
id | user_id | text
```

post_attachment:

```
id | post_id | path | type
```

company model:

```
public function users() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\User')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
}
```

user model:

```
public function posts() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

posts model:

```
public function images(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\PostsAttachment')->where("type", "image");
}
```

I want to get all company who have user(s) that have post(s) with minimal 2 images attachment. Anyone can help me?

I tried  `Company::has('users.posts.images', '<', 2)->get();` but it also give companies who has user image below 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eloquent you could write your logic as

```
$companies = Company::has('users.posts.images')->get();
```

[See Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: I am tried
`Company::has('users.posts.images',">", 2)->get();` and `Company::has('users.posts.images')->get();` but give same result, I will edit my question

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Your comment isn't clear enough, Can you update your question and add details for what you are trying to achieve, For above queries there is difference one will give you if attachment  count is greater than 2 and other statement will give you companies who have at least one attachment

Comment: I am sorry, difficult to tell more details, but after I tried again it turned out that your answer was correct. So thanks you